# Using Awk to print a column if only it meets criteria

Tags: bash, unix

I have a file called autodata.csv and has 20 columns of data. I am looking to print only the rows with "6" being in column 8 (for cylinders).

So, I have this working but only printing the number 6, rather than all the columns:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read x
do

echo $x | awk -F ',' ' { print $8=6} '

done
```

But if I add the rest of the columns it gives me errors:

```
echo $x | awk -F',' ' { print $1":"$2":"$4":"$7":"$8=6}'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
awk -F ',' '{ if ($8 == 6) { print $1":"$2":"$4":"$7":"$8 } }'
```

Comment: And if I wanted to do something like 6 and above I could do <6?

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
awk -F ',' '$8 == "6" {print $0}'
```